Android Studio Error uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details
This is my code, and when i run the app it shows this error in my MainActivity.java

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

I try to fix buy Alt+Enter and when it success the app i built got crash
package com.first.moviebay.Activities;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.CompositePageTransformer;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.MarginPageTransformer;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.first.moviebay.Adapters.SlidersAdapter;
import com.first.moviebay.Domains.SliderItems;
import com.first.moviebay.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private Handler sliderHandler =new Handler();
    private Runnable sliderRunnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            binding.viewPager2.setCurrentItem(binding.viewPager2.getCurrentItem()+1);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        Window w=getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        initBanner();
    }

    private void initBanner() {
        DatabaseReference myRef=database.getReference("Banners");
        binding.progressBarBanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ArrayList<SliderItems> items=new ArrayList<>();
        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot issue:snapshot.getChildren()){
                        items.add(issue.getValue(SliderItems.class));
                    }
                    banners(items);
                    binding.progressBarBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void banners(ArrayList<SliderItems> items){
        binding.viewPager2.setAdapter(new SlidersAdapter(items,binding.viewPager2));
        binding.viewPager2.setClipToPadding(false);
        binding.viewPager2.setClipChildren(false);
        binding.viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        binding.viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

        CompositePageTransformer compositePageTransformer=new CompositePageTransformer();
        compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(40));
        compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
                float r=1-Math.abs(position);
                page.setScaleY(0.85f+r*0.15f);
            }
        });

        binding.viewPager2.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer);
        binding.viewPager2.setCurrentItem(1);
        binding.viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                sliderHandler.removeCallbacks(sliderRunnable);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sliderHandler.removeCallbacks(sliderRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sliderHandler.postDelayed(sliderRunnable, 2000);
    }
}

When i run i got error but the device can run also the app installed but then the app crash/force close

Note: D:\SP 2024\PPB\TubesPB\app\src\main\java\com\first\moviebay\Activities\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\SP 2024\PPB\TubesPB\app\src\main\java\com\first\moviebay\Adapters\SlidersAdapter.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Thanks for help
